# Mocking DbContext - can't insert new objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx

I'm trying to use code similar to query scenario from link above.
EF 6.1 + Moq.
It works fine with pre-populated data like this (I can query them without any problem):

```
_context = new Mock<MyContext>();

IQueryable<users> users = new List<users>
        {
            new users{id = 1, email = "test@test.pl", password = "test", created = DateTime.Now, modified = DateTime.Now},
            new users{id = 2, email = "test2@test.pl", password = "test", created = DateTime.Now, modified = DateTime.Now},
        }.AsQueryable();
var mockUsers = new Mock<DbSet<users>>();
        mockUsers.As<IQueryable<users>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(users.Provider);
        mockUsers.As<IQueryable<users>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(users.Expression);
        mockUsers.As<IQueryable<users>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(users.ElementType);
        mockUsers.As<IQueryable<users>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(users.GetEnumerator());

_context.Setup(m => m.users).Returns(mockUsers.Object);
```

But when I try to add new object in my test method, it doesn't work:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void AddUser()
    {
        _context.Object.users.Add(new users { email = "test3@test.pl", password = "test", created = DateTime.Now, modified = DateTime.Now });
        _context.Object.SaveChanges();
        var count = _context.Object.users.Count();
        Assert.AreEqual(3, count); // count == 2 instead 3
    }
```

Would it be possible to modify it, so my mocked context would actually apply SaveChanges? Am I thinking correctly or this approach would be wrong for some reason?

If i use non-query approach I won't be able to use:

```
mockContext.Object.users.Count()
```

Let's say I have method to test, with fragment like this:

```
 context.cards.Add(card);
 context.SaveChanges();
 SetCardForUser(card.id, user);

 protected void SetCardForUser(long cardId, users user)
    {
        user.card_id = cardId;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I need card.id returned after inserting object to database.
Should I keep strictly to SRP and have methods that will simply do only one thing?

How would I test this method where only AddCardAndStartAuthCharge is public and other methods are protected? :

```
public async Task<long> AddCardAndStartAuthCharge(CardModel model, string username)
    {
        var hash = await GetHashForCardAuth(model);
        var CardWithId = AddCardToDatabase(model, username);
        long chargeId = AddHashToCard(CardWithId, hash);
        return chargeId;
    }
```

Comment: If you look, there is an `Add` scenario in the link you posted: *Testing non-query scenarios*

Comment: I edited my questions to better explain my problem.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you say you need to modify the card ID and retrieve the ID of an object after you saved it. Ids are handled by EF, and in my experience there is no need to modify or use the corresponding property yourself.  Why would you need to do that?

Comment: It's connected with my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901691/inserting-two-entites-with-foreign-keys-in-one-turn

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is absolutely no need to manage IDs yourself when using EntityFramework. Observe this code snippet:

```
MyContext context = new MyContext();
User user = new User() { Name = "Name1" };
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
Console.WriteLine(user.Id);
```

After performing the `SaveChanges` is given an ID automatically. Therefore snippets like the one from your other question can be easily refactored.

```
//Old
public CardModel AddCard(CardModel model, string username)
{
    var user = context.users.Where(x => x.email.ToLower() == username.ToLower()).First();
    var card = new cards()
    {
        created = DateTime.Now,
        modified = DateTime.Now,
        name = model.Name,
        type = model.CardType,
        user_id = user.id
    };
    context.cards.Add(card);
    context.SaveChanges();
    model.Id = card.id;
    return model;
}

//New
public CardModel AddCard(CardModel model, string username)
{
    var user = context.users.Where(x => x.email.ToLower() == username.ToLower()).First();
    user.Cards.Add(model)
    user.SaveOrUpdate()
    return model;
}
```

Observe that at no point something like `model.Id = card.id` is necessary!

This will most likely not work without some changes to your existing models. You will have to configure EntityFramework to properly cascade changes in a model to all child models (e.g. if a `User`is deleted, delete all `Cards`).

Now, for your question. If you refactor your code according the above, you will never depend on `SaveChanges()` and the `DBSet`s contained in your context to provide your models.

Since you are using mocks, the ID won't change either, but given your code you should not ever have to explicitly use any IDs.

The mocks you already have will be sufficient since you never have to retrieve the model you just added to the context from said context in order to use it. Keeping this in mind it is neither necessary to mock the consequences of `SaveChanges` nor is it necessary to mock things like `Count`.

Comment: Is user.Cards.Add(model) possible in this case if I don't use Automapper or entity directly? Normally I use view models like CardModel and entities like cards in this example and map between them either manually or with automapper/linq selects.

Comment: @Adiqq Well, it really depends on your specific case. As it currently stands: No.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to Mock Saving method. Please look at this:

```
IQualityIssuesRepository qir = new QualityIssuesRepository();
        Mock<IQualityIssuesRepository> qualityIssuesRepository = new Mock<IQualityIssuesRepository>();
qualityIssuesRepository.CallBase = true;
Action<List<int>, int> saveNotification = qir.SaveNotification;
qualityIssuesRepository.Setup(p => p.SaveNotification(It.IsAny<List<int>>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Callback(saveNotification);
```

You should setup the Save method in your mocked repository. Just create instance of that repo, and assing the method to mocked repository. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider mocking out at a higher level of abstraction then the tight coupling you have with the tool your using.

Perhaps your view-model should rely on services and not a detail of the tool that your using (i.e. IIsesServiceChannel).

Here's an example:

I generally use IServices, Services, and MockServices.

- IServices provides the available operations that all business logic must invoke methods on.
- Services is the data access layer that my code-behind injects into view-model (i.e. actual database).
- MockServices is the data access layer that my unit tests injects to the view-model (i.e. mock data).

**IServices:**

```
public interface IServices
{
    IEnumerable<Warehouse> LoadSupply(Lookup lookup);
    IEnumerable<Demand> LoadDemand(IEnumerable<string> stockCodes, int daysFilter, Lookup lookup);

    IEnumerable<Inventory> LoadParts(int daysFilter);
    Narration LoadNarration(string stockCode);
    IEnumerable<PurchaseHistory> LoadPurchaseHistory(string stockCode);

    IEnumerable<StockAlternative> LoadAlternativeStockCodes();
    AdditionalInfo GetSupplier(string stockCode);
}
```

**MockServices:**

```
public class MockServices : IServices
{
    #region Constants
    const int DEFAULT_TIMELINE = 30;
    #endregion

    #region Singleton
    static MockServices _mockServices = null;

    private MockServices()
    {
    }

    public static MockServices Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mockServices == null)
            {
                _mockServices = new MockServices();
            }

            return _mockServices;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Members
    IEnumerable<Warehouse> _supply = null;
    IEnumerable<Demand> _demand = null;
    IEnumerable<StockAlternative> _stockAlternatives = null;
    IConfirmationInteraction _refreshConfirmationDialog = null;
    IConfirmationInteraction _extendedTimelineConfirmationDialog = null;
    #endregion

    #region Boot
    public MockServices(IEnumerable<Warehouse> supply, IEnumerable<Demand> demand, IEnumerable<StockAlternative> stockAlternatives, IConfirmationInteraction refreshConfirmationDialog, IConfirmationInteraction extendedTimelineConfirmationDialog)
    {
        _supply = supply;
        _demand = demand;
        _stockAlternatives = stockAlternatives;
        _refreshConfirmationDialog = refreshConfirmationDialog;
        _extendedTimelineConfirmationDialog = extendedTimelineConfirmationDialog;
    }

    public IEnumerable<StockAlternative> LoadAlternativeStockCodes()
    {
        return _stockAlternatives;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Warehouse> LoadSupply(Lookup lookup)
    {
        return _supply;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Demand> LoadDemand(IEnumerable<string> stockCodes, int daysFilter, Syspro.Business.Lookup lookup)
    {
        return _demand;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Inventory> LoadParts(int daysFilter)
    {
        var job1 = new Job() { Id = Globals.jobId1, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now, StockCode = Globals.stockCode100 };
        var job2 = new Job() { Id = Globals.jobId2, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now, StockCode = Globals.stockCode200 };
        var job3 = new Job() { Id = Globals.jobId3, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now, StockCode = Globals.stockCode300 };

        return new HashSet<Inventory>()
        {
            new Inventory() { StockCode = Globals.stockCode100, UnitQTYRequired = 1, Category = "Category_1", Details = new PartDetails() { Warehouse = Globals.Instance.warehouse1, Job = job1} },
            new Inventory() { StockCode = Globals.stockCode200, UnitQTYRequired = 2, Category = "Category_1", Details = new PartDetails() { Warehouse = Globals.Instance.warehouse1, Job = job2} },
            new Inventory() { StockCode = Globals.stockCode300, UnitQTYRequired = 3, Category = "Category_1", Details = new PartDetails() { Warehouse = Globals.Instance.warehouse1, Job = job3} },
        };
    }
    #endregion

    #region Selection
    public Narration LoadNarration(string stockCode)
    {
        return new Narration()
        {
            Text = "Some description"
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<PurchaseHistory> LoadPurchaseHistory(string stockCode)
    {
        return new List<PurchaseHistory>();
    }

    public AdditionalInfo GetSupplier(string stockCode)
    {
        return new AdditionalInfo()
        {
            SupplierName = "Some supplier name"
        };
    }
    #endregion

    #region Creation
    public Inject Dependencies(IEnumerable<Warehouse> supply, IEnumerable<Demand> demand, IEnumerable<StockAlternative> stockAlternatives, IConfirmationInteraction refreshConfirmation = null, IConfirmationInteraction extendedTimelineConfirmation = null)
    {
        return new Inject()
        {
            Services = new MockServices(supply, demand, stockAlternatives, refreshConfirmation, extendedTimelineConfirmation),

            Lookup = new Lookup()
            {
                PartKeyToCachedParts = new Dictionary<string, Inventory>(),
                PartkeyToStockcode = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
                DaysRemainingToCompletedJobs = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<Job>>(),
.
.
.

            },

            DaysFilterDefault = DEFAULT_TIMELINE,
            FilterOnShortage = true,
            PartCache = null
        };
    }

    public List<StockAlternative> Alternatives()
    {
        var stockAlternatives = new List<StockAlternative>() { new StockAlternative() { StockCode = Globals.stockCode100, AlternativeStockcode = Globals.stockCode100Alt1 } };
        return stockAlternatives;
    }

    public List<Demand> Demand()
    {
        var demand = new List<Demand>()
        {
            new Demand(){ Job = new Job{ Id = Globals.jobId1, StockCode = Globals.stockCode100, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now}, StockCode = Globals.stockCode100, RequiredQTY = 1}, 
            new Demand(){ Job = new Job{ Id = Globals.jobId2, StockCode = Globals.stockCode200, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now}, StockCode = Globals.stockCode200, RequiredQTY = 2}, 
        };
        return demand;
    }

    public List<Warehouse> Supply()
    {
        var supply = new List<Warehouse>() 
        { 
            Globals.Instance.warehouse1, 
            Globals.Instance.warehouse2, 
            Globals.Instance.warehouse3,
        };
        return supply;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Services:**

```
public class Services : IServices
{
    #region Singleton
    static Services services = null;

    private Services()
    {
    }

    public static Services Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (services == null)
            {
                services = new Services();
            }

            return services;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public IEnumerable<Inventory> LoadParts(int daysFilter)
    {
        return InventoryRepository.Instance.Get(daysFilter);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Warehouse> LoadSupply(Lookup lookup)
    {
        return SupplyRepository.Instance.Get(lookup);
    }

    public IEnumerable<StockAlternative> LoadAlternativeStockCodes()
    {
        return InventoryRepository.Instance.GetAlternatives();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Demand> LoadDemand(IEnumerable<string> stockCodes, int daysFilter, Lookup lookup)
    {
        return DemandRepository.Instance.Get(stockCodes, daysFilter, lookup);
    }
.
.
.
```

**Unit Test:**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void shortage_exists()
    {
        // Setup
        var supply = new List<Warehouse>() { Globals.Instance.warehouse1, Globals.Instance.warehouse2, Globals.Instance.warehouse3 };
        Globals.Instance.warehouse1.TotalQty = 1;
        Globals.Instance.warehouse2.TotalQty = 2;
        Globals.Instance.warehouse3.TotalQty = 3;

        var demand = new List<Demand>()
        {
            new Demand(){ Job = new Job{ Id = Globals.jobId1, StockCode = Globals.stockCode100, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now}, StockCode = Globals.stockCode100, RequiredQTY = 1}, 
            new Demand(){ Job = new Job{ Id = Globals.jobId2, StockCode = Globals.stockCode200, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now}, StockCode = Globals.stockCode200, RequiredQTY = 3}, 
            new Demand(){ Job = new Job{ Id = Globals.jobId3, StockCode = Globals.stockCode300, AssembledRequiredDate = DateTime.Now}, StockCode = Globals.stockCode300, RequiredQTY = 4}, 
        };

        var alternatives = _mock.Alternatives();
        var dependencies = _mock.Dependencies(supply, demand, alternatives);

        var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        viewModel.Register(dependencies);

        // Test
        viewModel.Load();

        AwaitCompletion(viewModel);

        // Verify
        var part100IsNotShort = dependencies.PartCache.Where(p => (p.StockCode == Globals.stockCode100) && (!p.HasShortage)).Single() != null;
        var part200IsShort = dependencies.PartCache.Where(p => (p.StockCode == Globals.stockCode200) && (p.HasShortage)).Single() != null;
        var part300IsShort = dependencies.PartCache.Where(p => (p.StockCode == Globals.stockCode300) && (p.HasShortage)).Single() != null;

        Assert.AreEqual(true, part100IsNotShort &&
                                part200IsShort &&
                                part300IsShort);
    }
```

**CodeBehnd:**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.viewModel = this.DataContext as MainViewModel;

                var dependencies = GetDependencies();
                this.viewModel.Register(dependencies);
.
.
.
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    public MyViewModel()
    {
.
.
.
    public void Register(Inject dependencies)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Injected = dependencies;

            this.Injected.RefreshConfirmation.RequestConfirmation += (message, caption) =>
                {
                    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                    return result;
                };

            this.Injected.ExtendTimelineConfirmation.RequestConfirmation += (message, caption) =>
                {
                    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                    return result;
                };

.
.
.
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        }
    }
```